# Empty ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

Given two functions `x[T],y[T]`

```
x[T_] := (100000 T)/(47 Log[18/(-7 + 25 Abs[Cos[100 \[Pi] T]])])
y[T_] := 100 (-(7/500) + (7 T)/5 - (5 T (-1 + Abs[Cos[100 \[Pi] T]]))/Log[18/(-7 + 25 Abs[Cos[100 \[Pi] T]])] + Sin[100 \[Pi] T]/(20 \[Pi]))
```

the plot is easily created

```
Plot[{x[u], y[u]}, {u, .006, .01}]
```

[image]

If I try `ParametricPlot`   (with adjusted PlotRange and AspectRatio) I get an empty plot

```
ParametricPlot[{x[u], y[u]}, {u, .006, .01},PlotRange -> {{0, 1500}, {0, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**remark:**
Meanwhile I found a workaround by decreasing the plotintervall:

```
ParametricPlot[ {x[u], y[u]} , {u, .006, .01 - .001},AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Knowing that `u==0.01`is `Indeterminate` unfortunately I can't exclude it:

```
ParametricPlot[ {x[u], y[u]} , {u, .006, .01  },AspectRatio ->1,Exclusions->{0.01}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Enlarge PlotPoints or MaxRecursion, both yield the desired plot.

```
ParametricPlot[{x[u], y[u]}, {u, .006, .01}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1500}, {0, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotPoints -> 500]

ParametricPlot[{x[u], y[u]}, {u, .006, .01}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1500}, {0, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   MaxRecursion -> 10]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering why`MaxRecursion->` is needed in the `ParametricPlot` , but not in `Plot`?